# Tag removal request: [hayes]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, synonym-request

Can we remove the [hayes](/questions/tagged/hayes) tag and make it a synonym for [at-command](/questions/tagged/at-command) instead? There are only two questions tagged with this, and both are tagged with [at-command](/questions/tagged/at-command) as well.

Comment: I don't think we need to alias for 2 questions.

Comment: As of now no questions have that tag. It will disappear within 24 hours.

Comment: @Bart Thanks. To prevent this tag from being created again in the future, it should be either blacklisted or being created as an alias. Of those two options I think creating it as an alias is the better option.

Comment: @hlovdal No, it shouldn't. We'll take care of it if it pops up again. What if someone creates a programming language named hayes that gets traction? Shouldn't it deserve the tag, rather than serial commands which already have their own?

Answer (score 1):

The tag has been removed, but I strongly disagree that this deserves a synonym, and here's why.

- The tag only had 2 questions. Generally, synonyms should have a significant amount of questions behind them to be proposed candidates for synonymization™, as they would come back on their own over time.
- Both of the questions tagged as such were already tagged with it's proposed synonym. That indicates that it possible could be a separate tag from the synonym, although in this case that is unlikely.
- The original tag is such that it could be re-used. An example would be someone creating a programming language called 'Hayes' down the road, which would then cause questions to either be mis-tagged, or tagged with `hayes-language` instead, hurting searchability.

There's probably more reasons why not to synonymize it, but those are the ones off the top of my head.

Comment: Point 1: The best argument, but in my opinion weak. AT commands is quite a narrow topic, there is just 244 questions tagged `at-command`. So on a relative scale it is not that insignificant.

Comment: Point 2: Not relevant. The unlikeliness equals exactly zero in this case.

Comment: Point 3: It might certainly be that someone invents a programming language called hayes. But the probability of that is several order of magnitudes lower than the probability that some user will try to create a `hayes` tag when asking a question. We cannot avoid using words just because there is a tiny, tiny chance that maybe sometime in the distant future it might be used in some specific way.

Answer (score -2):

I think it should be a synonym, and here's why

- The Hayes name is very commonly associated with AT commands{1}. In
  the future when some user comes here to ask a question about AT
  commands, it is not unlikely that he/she will think that `hayes` is
  good description when being unaware of the `at-command` tag. Much
  the same way as `i18n` is an synonym for
  `internationalization`, because it is very likely that some users
  in the future will create questions using `i18n` rather than
  `internationalization`.

Why would that be bad? Well in best case `hayes` would be put on
in addition to `at-command` but in worst case the author will just
use `hayes` and miss out on `at-command` (which already is an
underused tag, several of the `modem` questions ought to have this
tag for instance).

{1}
To put things in perspective with some google searches:

```
hayes modem               1 950 000 results
"at command" modem          990 000 results
hayes                   174 000 000 results
"at command"              1 840 000 results
```

Notice that `hayes modem` gives more results than `"at command"`.

Comment: I think you miss the point of a synonym. It should only be used when the source tag is likely to come back - there's no need for a synonym for a tag that's not popular.

Comment: I think you and I put severely different meanings into the word `likely`. Can you explain at what point you would start considering the possibility for a tag to re-appear to be likely?

Comment: Just because the tag has low activity does not mean that it is dead (there were 20 questions created last 30 days). Assuming maybe 200 new questions the next year and a 0.5% probability that a user will try to use `hayes` that gives an expectancy of one such question within a year.  In my view, this is a problem that is not yet solved and that will reappear. The moderators are already complaining about an overwhelmingly amount of janitoring tasks.  why not solve the problem right now once and for all and never have to deal with it again?

Comment: If 'hayes' (which was created in 2009) had more than 100 questions, then it becomes a candidate for synonymization in my opinion. After 4 years, only 2 questions means it won't come back any time soon.

Comment: Wait - where do you see 20 questions in 30 days? According to this [Data.SE query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/105921) (which lags behind SO by several days) there were only ever 2 questions with it.

Comment: At http://stackoverflow.com/tags/at-command/topusers it says 20 questions last 30 days.

Comment: that's for [tag:at-command] and not [tag:hayes]. Nobody *wanted* to use hayes at all over the course of 4 years, why would that suddenly change?

Comment: I think your data analysis is flawed. Data explorer is just a snapshot of the current site, so what your query shows is noting other than what was stated in the original question, that at time of its creation there were two questions tagged. Or did I miss something, does it show something else?